# "I did check" or "I checked" in answer

Tags: do-support, emphasis

Que : did you check that file before sending ?

Ans 1 : yes, I did check that file before sending.

Ans 2 : yes, I checked that file before sending.

Which answer is appropriate Ans 1 or Ans. 2 ? Why ?

Comment: Neither is "appropriate" as a real-world answer to the question as posed. The most natural response is simply "Yes" - or possibly "Yes, I did" as a more emphatic version.

Comment: I'd answer the question with just "I did," but please edit your *question title* - the form "did checked" is *never* correct!

Comment: You're looking for an 'answer from a reputable source': check this out: https://www.grammar.cl/Past/Short_Answers.htm  In particular, note where it says "long answers usually sound repetitive and are not commonly used."  This source came up as the second result by doing a Google search for the (auto-suggested) term *how to answer question with did*.

Comment: [correction: before sending **it** is more idiomatic.]

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that answer 1 uses "do-support". In sentences such as this one, do-support creates what is often called the "emphatic form" of a verb phrase, providing emphasis to the statement. According to one syntax guide:

> In the simplest case, *do* support affects affirmative sentences containing a finite verb whose truth is being emphasized. . . . This form of *do* then receives emphatic stress. (Beatrice Santorini and Anthony Kroch, [*The syntax of natural language: An online introduction*](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/%7Ebeatrice/syntax-textbook/box-modals.html#emphasis), 2007)

Wikipedia gives the following example of a response to a question:

> *Did Bill eat his breakfast? Yes, he did eat his breakfast* (*did* emphasizes the positive answer, which may be unexpected). (["*Do*-support"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support#For_emphasis), Wikipedia)

Answer 2 has the same meaning as answer 1 but lacks the emphasis of do-support. Therefore, which answer you pick should depend on whether you want to emphasize it or not. (Without more context, it's impossible for me to determine whether that would be warranted.)

Both answers are grammatically correct and could be entirely natural in certain contexts, but, as others have mentioned in comments, a more typical answer wouldn't repeat so many words from the question.

Answer (score 0):

They are both okay, although most people would use #2 because it's simpler/shorter.  #1 is a little pedantic, and I would use it if I wanted to send a (somewhat obnoxious) message to the questioner along the lines of, "Yes *of course* I checked that, why are you even *asking* me this!"

Also, as @FumbleFingers has pointed out, even repeating most of the question in the answer is overly formal.  Most people would say, "Yes, I checked it."